# How to stop a UILabel scrolling?

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have several UILabels. I setup a UIScrollView within a app that works fine. The problem that I'm having is I want some UILabels to scroll and some to remain frozen. I don't think this is a coding problem as much as a interface builder issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the **UILabel** as **subView** of **scrollView** which you want to scroll. And add the **UILabel** as **subView** of **self.view** which you dont want to scroll.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with InterfaceBuilder? How would I go about adding the UILabels to subView

Comment: If you need to add a label programmatically then you should to add it by [self.view addSubView:label] or [scrollView addSubView:label].

Answer (score 6):

If you mean you want the labels to be fixed on top of the scrollview, then simply drag them out in interface builder so they're at the same level in the hierarchy and not inside of the scrollview.[image]